# Skin Cancer Classifier: Unable to find normal skin images

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, dataset, conv-neural-network

**Summary:**

I’m working with TensorFlow to build a skin cancer classifier, and I have found many images for skin cancer with labels. My problem is that I haven’t found any images for normal skin or false skin cancer. I noticed all blogs referred to a skin cancer dataset but never to normal skin images.

**Questions:**

How can the network know what is and what is not skin cancer?

If a network is trained only with types of cancer and I give a normal skin image will it predict one of the skin cancer types?

**One of the blogs:**

https://medium.com/intech-conseil-expertise/detect-mole-cancer-with-your-smartphone-using-deep-learning-8afad1efde8a

P.S. I’m new to deep learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That problem should be quite easy to resolve by pics of lots of healthy people pics!

You can't perform supervised learning without a database of control images. You could redefine the question against the images that you have.

If you can't do either you are stuck with unsupervised learning and your positive images will serve only to verify your unsupervised learning conclusions. You are hoping your unsupervised learning will yield two groups and if correct one of the group should map against your positive images. Then its solved without the control data set.

If you can successfully map your positive images onto your output then the remainder becomes your control set for supervised learning, i.e. they become your training set.